# Find similarity between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, levenshtein-distance

I have lots of profiles as nodes and would like to match nodes whose name property have a certain string similarity.

How is that possible with Neo4j?

Example data:

```
NodeA: {
    "name": "Jacob F Saxberg"
},
NodeB: {
    "name": "Jacob Friis Saxberg"
}
```

I'd like to get the Levenshtein distance (4) or something similar with Neo4j.

Comment: Are you wanting to perform something like this with Cypher, or would you be okay with either implementing your own Java code or Gremlin?

Comment: I had hoped for Cypher, but Gremlin looks interesting if I can build it in Node.js which is what I use for my app?

Comment: In Cypher, I don't believe you can define custom functions like this, and there doesn't seem to be a function for performing this type of algorithm. Gremlin however allows you full access to `Groovy`, so you can write functions that perform this.

Comment: Normally, I would just use a regular expression for comparisons of text, but this is a very interesting subject for finding the degree of similarity. If your nodes are in an index, it will be easier to reference each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Levenshtein distance is a function of two nodes `f(nodeA, nodeB)` and since it's symmetric ( `f(nodeA,nodeB)==f(nodeB,NodeA)` ) it might be a good choice to store the result of Levenshtein distance as a property on a relationship between nodeA and node B.

You can use cypher to find all the nodes for which the Levensthein distance should be calculated. Using Java (or your preferred client language) you can iterate of the nodes found, do the math and write the result back into the graph.

Comment: maybe he can keep the whole name as property like he has it now, and create new nodes for each alphabet letter [a-z][A-Z] and new rels to each of the letter the original name node has in its name property. than, comparing 2 node for the distance could look like: `START n1=node(1), n2=node(2) MATCH n1-[:letter]-l-[:letter]-n2 WITH n1,n2,l, count(*) as similar RETURN length(n1.name-similar)+length(n2.name-similar) as distance;`

Comment: but thats more tricky that it seemed first time to me. for repeating letters one would have to add some weight to the `letter` rels. also, for huge database the letter nodes could grow up to tons of rels and would not perform fast.

Comment: I'm using fast-levenshtein to compile the distance between each node and saving it for those <= 1. Thanks all.